# S3 Lifecycle Rule Keeps Disappearing in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage-class

I am trying to transition a bucket full of Standard Tier storage class objects to Intelligent-Tirering class objects one time. I created the following Lifecycle Rule to transition them all:

[image]

This appears in my Lifecycle rules list, I have correctly have 2 rules:

[image]

But when I return in around 1 hour the rule is missing and the transition hasn't happened. I have only one original rule remaining again.

[image]

Why does it keep disappearing/deleting? and how do I fix this to transition the objects to the Intelligent-Tirering storage class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from @allan-chua and Laravel Vapor support it looks like Vapor clears the lifecycle rules of any managed buckets on deployment. There are 2 solutions here:

1. In my case, I can set the lifecycle rule and not deploy until it has been executed.
2. Remove the bucket from the vapor.yml file and manually update the filesystem config in the environment instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there's some sort of automation that removes your lifecycle rule (Check with your infra, devops or security teams). You could use CloudTrail to check which principal is deleting your S3 lifecycle rule(s).

See:

[Viewing recent CloudTrail management events in the CloudTrail console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Laravel Vapor was rewriting my lifecycle rules on deployment.

Comment: Glad you found the guilty principal @alexmcfarlane!